# Using data from the fetch API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

When I store data as a JSON variable, I can normally create variables from it in JS like this:

```
var person = {"name":"adam"};
var name = person.name;
```

When I use the fetch API though to load the resource, I am unable to create variables from the data in this same way. I know the data has loaded though as I can log it and browse it in the console.

I am currently trying to do this with the following:

```
  var person;
        fetch(url)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => person = data)

            var name = person.name
```

Assuming that the (url) loads the same data as above, how would I set the 'name' variable as the 'name' field in the json file?

Comment: You do it within the then function. In the space where you currently have "var name=person.name" the fetch and associated promises have not yet executed so those values will be undefined.

Answer (score 4):

`fetch` is `asynchronous call` and you are assigning `name` outside of `then`. so it will not work as intended.
try :-

```
var person, name;
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
           person = data;
           name = person.name;
       })
```

**Note :-** I have declared name globally with person, you can change its scoping accordingto your need. but it will be available after that `async` call

Answer (score 2):

Because there are two asynchronous steps involved, you can use the following approach with `async await`:

```js
(async () => {
    const person = await (await fetch(url)).json();
    const name = person.name
    console.log( name );
    //other code needing person object
})();
```